# Como fazer um formulário trasnparente com bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-3

Queria montar um formulário transparente, como o exemplo da foto[image: exemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai o código utilizando a class padrão do bootstrap e adicionando o seguinte style:

```
<style>
                    input.transparent-input{
                    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
                    border:none !important;
                    }
</style>

<input class="form-control transparent-input" type='text' name='nome' placeholder="Titulo">
```